# apidata.map is not a function : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

Can someone please tell me why i am getting this error . I tried fixing it all day, but I could not fix it. So at last i had to come at stackoverflow

This is my code : App.js

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [inputvalue, setInputvalue] = useState(" ");
  const [apidata, setApidata] = useState([]);
  const [finalpoint, setFinalpoint] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=+${inputvalue}&days=3`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "7f89bf16ebmsh9dff0f23f963d34p190691jsn264543e18108",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setApidata(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, [finalpoint]);

  const onchangeinput = (e) => {
    setInputvalue(e.target.value);
  };

  const onsubmithandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFinalpoint(inputvalue); 
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        <h2>Welcome To weather App </h2>
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={onsubmithandler}>
        <input type="text" value={inputvalue} onChange={onchangeinput} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {apidata.map((data, i) => {
        return <h1>{data.current.feelslike_c}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
    //Map
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the error I am getting :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPs6e.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm seeing is the api is initially returning an error object.  Also, when the proper data is returned, it comes back as an object. When setting your state, you will have to set data inside of an array (if you want to use the map method). You will also have to handle the error by doing something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputvalue, setInputvalue] = useState(" ");
  const [apidata, setApidata] = useState([]);
  const [finalpoint, setFinalpoint] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=+${inputvalue}&days=3`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "7f89bf16ebmsh9dff0f23f963d34p190691jsn264543e18108"
        }
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.error) return null;
        setApidata([data]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, [finalpoint]);

  const onchangeinput = (e) => {
    setInputvalue(e.target.value);
  };

  const onsubmithandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFinalpoint(inputvalue);
  };

  console.log("test", apidata);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        <h2>Welcome To weather App </h2>
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={onsubmithandler}>
        <input type="text" value={inputvalue} onChange={onchangeinput} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {apidata.length
        ? apidata.map((data, i) => {
            return <h1 key={i}>{data.current.feelslike_c}</h1>;
          })
        : null}
    </div>
    //Map
  );
}
```

see working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-wind-06ywo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey , Thanks for the reply . The solution you provided works,Thank you. Can you please tell me what was wrong with my code and what did you do to fix it?

Comment: @ShazzyFazzy it looked like the response was initially an error object, so I basically made sure when setting the api data to state that it wasn't an error object.  Also, the response comes back as an object, so you needed to set the state as an array

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are receiving undefined here:

```
.then((data) => {
   setApidata(data);
 })
```

and overriding the state with undefined.